# So what was the secret behind the stainless steel of Doc's Delorean?

Tags: back-to-the-future

"If your going to build a time machine why not do it with some style besides the stainless steel construction made the flux dispersal.....watch out!"  He never got to finish his statement what was he going to say about the steel?

0.19 seconds.

What do you theorize the rest of his speech was meant to say? What was special about the steel casing? Could his flux capacitor have worked on his tow truck if he wanted to?

Answer (score -1):

Answer to the second question: "would tow truck work?" **Yes**. He even made a locomotive into a time machine.

Since Dr. Brown later used a locomotive as his time machine platform, the suggetion is that the choice of the Delorean, however, was mostly style, as he claimed in the movie, not necessity. A locomotive is mostly cast iron rather than steel, and definitely not *stainless* steel as the Delorean is. Metal itself might have been significant to the operation, or efficiency, of the flux capacitor, possibly even ferrous metal such as iron.

A modern car, with non-negligible amounts of other materials in the body might be questionable. A tow truck, of the same time frame as the Delorean, was nearly all metal, and most of that steel (even if not stainless steel), so using one wouldn't be an issue, from the point of view of the flux capacitor. Dr. Brown's tow truck, however, might have needed more work (and investment of money and time) before being able to reach the needed 88 MPH for transition.

Comment: A locomotive is not a tow truck.

Comment: @Valorum I never claimed a locomotive was a tow truck. The evidence that he used a locomotive as a time machine supports that he could have used anything he chose to, including his tow truck. A locomotive is mostly cast iron rather than steel, and definitely not _stainless_ steel like the Delorean. Metal itself might have been significant, possibly even ferrous metal such as iron. The choice of the Delorean, however, was mostly _style_, as he claimed, not necessity.

Comment: In the comics he uses (variously) a motorbike and a hot-air balloon. Neither of those have a metal cage.

Comment: @Valorum Further evidence that the Delorean was purely a stylistic choice, and that the tow truck could have worked. BTW, never new a hot-air balloon could reach 88 MPH!

Comment: He cuts the cable. The basket reaches 88mph within seconds.